# Symfony + DomCrawler - how to extract data attributes from a <div>

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

I'm using Symfony 2.8 & DomCrawler to parse a web site and I'm having a problem reading `data` attributes from a HTML entity. It might be as simple as a specific convention for `data` attributes, but I've not been able to find any references or examples on the web that discuss how to retrieve data attributes via DomCrawler.

Here are the details:

I have encountered an instance of this construct in the HTML I am parsing (from another web site, so I can't modify this HTML):

```
  <div class='slideshowclass' id='slideshow'>           
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/1.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/thumbs/1.jpg'></div>
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/2.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/thumbs/2.jpg'></div>
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/3.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/thumbs/3.jpg'></div>
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/4.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/thumbs/4.jpg'></div>
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/5.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/thumbs/5.jpg'></div>
    <div data-thumb='http://www.example.com/thumbs/6.jpg'
        data-src='http://www.example.com/6.jpg'></div>
  </div>
```

I'm using this code to search the block of `div`'s and return the `data-src` values:

```
function getList( Crawler $pWebDoc ) {
    $list = $pWebDoc->filter( 'div#slideshow');
    if ( !$list )
        return null;

    $retlist = null;
    $x = $list->count();
    if ( $x > 0 ) {
        /* @var $item Crawler */
        $retlist = $list->children()->each( function (Crawler $item, $i ) {
            return ( "$i:" . $item->attr( 'data-src' ));
        });
    }

    return ( $retlist );
}
```

From the DomCrawler docs I expect the `attr` function to return the `data-src` attribute value, but it returns null; the return from my function being an array of 6 elements with just the number and not additional text.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using the DOMDocument and XPath libraries.  XPath does provide the capability of returning array's of values instead of nodes.

```
/**
 * Filters the list of nodes with an XPath expression.
 *
 * The XPath expression should already be processed to apply it in the context of each node.
 *
 * @param string $xpath
 *
 * @return Crawler
 */
private function filterRelativeXPath($xpath)
{
    $prefixes = $this->findNamespacePrefixes($xpath);
    $crawler = $this->createSubCrawler(null);
    foreach ($this->nodes as $node) {
        $domxpath = $this->createDOMXPath($node->ownerDocument, $prefixes);
        $crawler->add($domxpath->query($xpath, $node));
    }
    return $crawler;
}
```

This function is from [Crawler.php](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/master/Crawler.php#L892).  My experience has been that the Crawler wasn't happy with complex xpath expressions, which resulted in switching from the DomCrawler to using xpath / dom directly.

Your base xpath query would be like `//div/@data-src`

Comment: Hi Shaun - thanks for that, but I'm not able to replace the given's in Symfony. Your suggested query would work fine (I tested it) but I simplified my requirement for the example, in reality, some situations might have text in the div container, which I would also need to access and store along with the attribute value - Larry